# Jackrabitt: set Username and Password

Tags: spring, apache, jackrabbit

I am new using JackRabbit. I have one problem, I need add the 
username and password to access to the repository. At the moment, I can 
access whit every password and user but, for my need, it is not 
secure.

I have found **jackrabbit-repo.xml** file. but I don't know where I have to add these params. (in security>LoginModule or Filesystem or anywhere).
please guide me by sample code if it is possible for you.

**Update:**

In *jackrabbit-repository.xml* has used simpleAccessManager and there was not any credentials for login. So I have changed it to *DefaultSecurityManager* and also add “adminId” param in LoginModule due to tell to Repository only adminUsers can login.

```
<SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" 
            workspaceName="security" />
<AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager"/>
<LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule">
    <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
</LoginModule>
```

Now, it works well unless anonymous user wants to login, in this case display error. and it is fine.
But I have faced to a new error. when in application tries to access files in repository, it will faced a below error.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not open Jcr Session; nested exception is javax.jcr.LoginException: LoginModule ignored Credentials

**Note:** PersistenManager dataType is *derby*. Because repository is not database.

Thanks

Comment: did you take a look at the manual? https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: @fateddy no I did not see it. are you sure it is related to jackrabbit?

Comment: whoops.. my bad. I was sure it read "rabbitmq". Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned error means if the user exists in the 3rd party system but the credentials don’t match it throws LoginException.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not open Jcr Session; nested exception is javax.jcr.LoginException: LoginModule ignored Credentials

[JAAS Authentication and Login Modules](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/site/tags/live-pre-markdown/oak/docs/security/authentication.html)

Don't need to change something in PersistenManager or something else in workspace.